# FTPClient.connect always waiting

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, ftp-client

```
public static FTPClient connect(String hostname, int port, int mode, String encoding) {

    FTPClient ftpClient = null;

    try {
        ftpClient = new FTPClient();

        //FTPClient.HostnameResolver resolver = new FTPClient.NatServerResolverImpl(ftpClient);
        //ftpClient.setPassiveNatWorkaroundStrategy(resolver);
        //ftpClient.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);

        ftpClient.setControlEncoding(encoding);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        // 连接 always waiting here!!!!!!!help please!!!
        ftpClient.connect(hostname, port);


        // 设置文件传输类型为二进制
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        switch (mode) {
        case MODE_TYPE_LOCAL_PASSIVE:
            // 本地被动
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            break;
        case MODE_TYPE_LOCAL_ACTIVE:
            // 本地主动
            ftpClient.enterLocalActiveMode();
            break;
        case MODE_TYPE_REMOTE_PASSIVE:
            // 远程被动
            ftpClient.enterRemotePassiveMode();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IOException("can not support mode type " + mode);
        }

        return ftpClient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (ftpClient != null && ftpClient.isConnected()) {
            try {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FTPClient client = FtpUtils.connect("103.143.106.197", 990);
    boolean login = FtpUtils.login(client, "xxx", "xxx");
    System.out.println(login);
}
```

[When I connect to a third party service，always waiting here，connect api.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnrfO.png)

Help please. I wonder if there is any configuration not set.

But I can connect to the FTP-server set up by the local machine。I can also connect to a third party FTP-server using Filezilla

Answer (score 0):

solved 。use  FTPClient client = new FTPSClient(true);
but But now there is a new problem, the uploaded file content is 0 bytes

Comment: Please either update your question with these changes, or create new question if the new problem is different then old